# Implement sticky items in Isotope masonry

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope to pull a list of posts and I use date as initial sort and allow users to sort by number of comments and recommendations. Everything works as expected.

Now what I need to accomplish is sticky posts. I have a set of posts that I would like to show randomly at interval of 10. Basically every 10 posts I would like to show one of these sticky posts.

I have figured out a way to do it at the initial load by injecting it in the loop at every 10 counts but my issue is after everything is loaded the change of sorting method messes this up. Is there any way I can inject a sticky post that would actually stick where it is supposed to no matter what the sort order is?

Answer (score 1):

Since I posted my last answer, a new product called [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/), from the creator of Isotope, has just been released.

Packery allows you to "stamp" any number of elements into any position you like. The remaining elements will neatly stack themselves around any fixed position (i.e. stamped) elements. It also does a better job at filling holes than isotope did.

My suggestion now would be to stamp your sticky posts at regular intervals and let Packery take care of the rest.

Packery has similar options and methods to isotope, so you may find that you can simply replace `.isotope()` calls with `.packery()` calls.

Packery also supports dragging with either the jQuery UI dragging or another addin called [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/). My only problem with Draggabilly is that there is no typescript definition file for it (yet). It also does not have the filtering capability like isotope, so may not be suitable for your task. *The creator of Isotope just told me in an email that he will be including the Packery layout into isotope in due course.*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to keep items at the start, or end, of an isotope display list is to make it part of the sort calculation. You just bias the sort values to be very small (for header items) or very large (for footer items).

To place them at intervals as you specify is a lot more complicated. You may need to sort them once to determine the overall order and then change the sort values, of the sticky items, to match where you want them inserted. Then you sort it all again.

*The alternative is to write a set of custom layout methods to replace the standard ones.*